# PostGIS & QGIS - PostGIS extension not accessible?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis, osgeo

I am having an odd problem with PostGreSQL/PostGIS on a Windows 10 machine.

I have successfully installed PostGIS many times without issue over the years, most recently last week on a Windows 10 machine at work.  I typically use QGIS as my client, so have a fair idea how these things need to be configured and operated.

Over the weekend, I downloaded the latest PostGres 11 installer with Stackbuilder, and installed PostGres & PostGIS.  pgAdmin4 seems to show everything is as it should be, and the sample 'postgis_23_sample' database is present and correct.

However, using QGIS DB Manager, when I try to connect to the database (on port 5432), whilst I can see the sample database and public schema, I cannot create a new table with geometry, or load any data (e.g. a simple shapefile) into the database.  The error message tells me that the 'addGeometryColumn' function does not exist.  I checked that the PostGIS extension is installed - which it is.  (I ran 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis' again to confirm this.)

So, I went back to pgAdmin, and tried creating a table with geometry via SQL, but got the same error: Creating a table without geometry works just fine.  As soon as I try to create a geometry column, I get the error.  It seems to me that the PostGIS extension is somehow not being 'found' by PostGres.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled various combinations of PostGres, PostGIS and QGIS over the weekend - but get the same error.  I created a new Windows account, and tried installing the stack there: same thing happened.

I also tried uninstalling everything and then installing the 'Portable GIS' stack by Astun.  These are much older versions of QGIS and PostGIS, but in theory the installer configures them all to work together.  (That, at least, has been my past experience of using Portable GIS at work.)  In this instance, I got the same error about the missing AddGeometryColumn function.

I am wondering if the various installs of PostGIS, QGIS and other tools over the last year or so have left some stubborn configuration entries (maybe in the registry?) that uninstallers have not been able to remove.  Could something like that be upsetting my recent PostGres insatllations?  It *feels* as though something is preventing DB clients from locating the PostGIS services on the assigned port.  Having said that, PostGres iteslef seems to be working fine, so maybe that is nonsense.

In any case, if anyone has any ideas how I can begin to debug and fix this, I would be hugely grateful.  (In the meantime, I am about to try the OSGeoLive Lubuntu VM, which at least will enable me to get some proper work done - I hope.)

Thank you...

Comment: check where the extension is installed. It might be pointing to an old location

Comment: Also, a PostgreSQL cluster contains several databases. Maybe you created the extension in the wrong database.

Comment: Thank you both - I will go and check both of those suggestions this evening.